# The imported packages in source codes are as submodules of my package when using setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools

I got a problem when using setup.py. An instances maybe clear:

Suppose I have **a.py** in my source folder as a module. I `import os` and implement a function named **'b'** in **a.py**. After ruunning `python setup.py install`, I should be able to `import a` and call `a.b`. But I can also call `a.os` in my case.

why does this happen? `a.os` should not appear, right? How to solve this issue? Looking for help!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you imported os in a.py, and then you imported a.py as a module. You may either redesign the `a` into a class or overwrite os as a function in a.py. Hope this helps.